# Efficient ruby line splitting

Tags: regular-expression, macro

I never made any plugins but I would like to get some advice for a specific case.

I'm writing a lot of ruby. Sometimes I have very long lines that I want to split.

Example:

```
MyModel.first_method.second_method(arg).third_method(arg.method)
```

to

```
MyModel
  .first_method
  .second_method(arg)
  .third_method(arg.method)
```

For the moment I have only the macro with `f.i<CR><ESC>w` but it fails when there is a dot inside parentheses. And I have to count how many times I want the macro to run.

I'm wondering what is the best way to optimise this ?

- Search for a regex that will avoid searching dot inside regex?
- For the moment I have only that `:s/\./\1\r./g` but my text is not indented and it doesn't deal with dot inside parentheses.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work for all the cases, but it seems to work on the example you provided:

```
:s/\v\ze(\(\w+)@<!\./\r  /g
```

---

The pattern used by the substitution command is: `\v\ze(\(\w+)@<!\.`

- `\v` is the very magic switch (useful to get rid of backslashes)
- `\ze` describes the end of the match. Since `\ze` is at the beginning of the pattern, it means that nothing will be substituted/removed. The replacement part of the substitution command will simply be inserted in front of the match.
- `(\(\w+)@<!` describes an open parenthesis and a word (`\(\w+`) which must not precede what will follow in the pattern (`@<!`). See `:h /\@<!` for more info on this, or google negative lookbehind.
- `\.` describes a dot

Whenever this pattern is found, `:s` inserts a newline and 2 spaces.

---

Edit: I've just realised it would fail if there are several dots inside a pair of parentheses. For example, if you have:

```
MyModel.first_method.second_method(arg).thrid_method(arg.method.foo.bar)
```

The previous substitution command will give:

```
MyModel
  .first_method
  .second_method(arg)
  .thrid_method(arg.method
  .foo
  .bar)
```

In this case, the following one could be more robust:

```
:s/\v\ze(\(\w+(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\r  /g
```

It should give:

```
MyModel
  .first_method
  .second_method(arg)
  .thrid_method(arg.method.foo.bar)
```

It's the same command as before, except this time, in your negative lookbehind, after the open parenthesis and a word, you add zero or more dots and words: `(\.\w+)*`

---

For the indentation problem, you could try this:

```
:s/\v\ze(\(\w+(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\="\n  " . matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')/g
```

It's, again, the same command, but this time the replacement part is the evaluation of an expression (`\=`) which returns a newline, 2 spaces and the level of indentation of the current line (`matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')`).

If you want to first remove a level of indentation on the line and remove 2 spaces, you could use `:s/^  //`, which would give:

```
:s/^  // | s/\v\ze(\(\w+(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\="\n  " . matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')/g
```

---

Edit2: In the previous command `()` is used to apply the multi `*` to the sub-pattern`\.\w+` and `@<!` to `\(\w+(\.\w+)*`. But in the replacement part, you don't use any backreference (`\1`, ..., `\9`). So, to make the regex a little bit faster, you could use `%()` instead (`:h /\%(`):

```
\%(\)   A pattern enclosed by escaped parentheses.  */\%(\)* */\%(* *E53*
    Just like \(\), but without counting it as a sub-expression.  This
    allows using more groups and it's a little bit faster.
    {not in Vi}
```

It would give:

```
:s/^  // | s/\v\ze%(\(\w+%(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\="\n  " . matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')/g
```

---

Edit3:
To turn this command into a mapping, you could add this into your `vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :s/^  // <Bar> s/\v\ze%(\(\w+%(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\="\n  " . matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')/g<CR>
```

In the following code:

```
class MyMethods
  def mymethod
    MyModel.first_method.second_method(arg).thrid_method(arg.method)
  end
end
```

... if you hit `<Leader>a` while the cursor is on the third line, it should give you:

```
class MyMethods
  def mymethod
  MyModel
    .first_method
    .second_method(arg)
    .thrid_method(arg.method)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tricky regex. Do you if it's possible to indent each line ? No need for extra spaces in `\r  \` then.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand, do you mean the substitution command should indent the lines beginning with a dot? It depends on how you indent your code, but if you use a tab you could use the same command and just replace the 2 spaces with a tab `\t` like this: `:s/\v(\(\w{-})@<!\./\r\t\./g`

Comment: I'm using `==` to indent. A gist with a proper code. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7735cf710289815c85ec719abad8c403 I've try few things for here without success http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732618/auto-indent-in-vim-string-replacement-new-line

Comment: Thank you for the gist, I understand now, I'm going to look for a solution and update the answer if I find something.

Comment: The last version is faster but their is a problem with indent. All the block is not properly indent. Also I've try to map to a leader key `map <Leader>a :s/^  // | s/\v\ze%(\(\w+%(\.\w+)*)@<!\./\="\n  " .  matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')/g<CR>` but I get trailing characters errors. :/

Comment: @BeniMio For the trailing characters errors, if you escape the pipe `\|` or if you replace it with `<bar>`, it should fix them. For the indentation problem, could you link a gist with a before / after the substitution?

Comment: @BeniMio For the indentation problem, I think in the first substitution, a space is missing, it should be `^` then 2 spaces. But in your code, it's `^` then only one space. Maybe you could try this: http://vpaste.net/dAhc7

Comment: Your last version works perfectly. You're a genius !

Answer (score 4):

A greedy match should be enough to do the job.

```
command! SplitDot let _s=@/ <bar> s/\v\.\w+%(\([^)]+\)|\{[^}]+})*/\r\0/g <bar> let @/=_s <bar> keepjumps normal! ``=']']
nnoremap <Leader>sd :SplitDot<CR>
```

The command works on the original example and this more complicated one:

```
class MyMethods
  def mymethod
    MyModel.first_method.second(arg).third_method(arg.method).select{|a| a.valid?}.join
  end
end
```

After using the mapping the output is below and the cursor is at `^`:

```
class MyMethods
  def mymethod
    MyModel
      .first_method
      .second(arg)
      .third_method(arg.method)
      .select{|a| a.valid?}
      .join
      ^
  end
end
```

The pattern is longer, but easier to extend to more cases like `{}` blocks.

[image: annotated regex and re-indent binding]

I prefer using the `=` method so Vim can indent for me using the indent rules already established by `filetype`.

Hope this helps and thanks for the idea. I've already used it in my own work flow.

Comment: This is very nice.